# Contribution tokens for receipts

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, tokens, receipts

We're trying to create online receipts for Memberships, Contributions and Events and we would like to include the contribution source, and payment instrument for in the receipts. The question is, is this possible? Since, the tokens that we're seeing in the message templates editor are only for contact, address, additional information, and some information from profiles that we made.

We're using CiviCRM 4.7.22.

Comment: You might try looking at the tokens available in the thank-you letter process for contributions - certain tokens are only accessible in certain areas of Civi, and you'll see more of the contribution tokens there (which you can then utilize in the receipt templates, which - assuming you're sending them out the standard way - should be able to use them).

Comment: You're right! Contribution tokens are available for thank you letters. I've tried using those tokens in our receipt template but they don't return any values. I think that it isn't really possible to use Contribution tokens in receipt templates. Might as well submit a feature request for this.

Comment: Are you referring to the receipt templates already in Civi (under System Workflows) or other templates?

Comment: @LesleyCarter-BackOffice, in other templates.

Comment: How would you be using these differently than the standard receipt templates for online transactions already included with Civi?

Comment: I'm sorry, under system workflows, actually. Anyways, we've modified some core code so that we could include the contribution source and payment instrument in the receipt template.

Comment: I hope that by "modified some core code" you actually mean you added a customization and didn't modify the core codebase directly... :-)  Glad you identified the correct tokens though!

Comment: That's funny cuz we kinda did. But, the original core files are intact we just copied it, created a symlink, and edited the file w/ the symlink. Not really a best practice right? 